# Xcode does not pick up pod updates

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

Started working on an outdated project that was developed in Swift 3 and Xcode8.

Trying to make it work under Xcode 10 and 9 (have them separately). Updated every known location with target platform to 11 and swift versions to 4/5. There were plenty of outdated pods that cause build errors, so I updated them with `pod update` and `pod install`. However, Xcode does not pick up the new versions, specifically `SKPhotoBrowser` and `SwiftDate` stay on versions 4.1.0 and 4.3.0 respectively, even though `pod install` states that versions 6.1.0 and 6.0.3 are installed.

The Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project

use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '11.0'

# Firebase pods
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'

#Facebook Authentication Pods
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

# Lottie Animation Framework
pod 'lottie-ios'

# Regular pods
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'BRYXBanner'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Instabug'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'PromiseKit'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'SKPhotoBrowser'
pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField'
pod 'Stripe' ##, :inhibit_warnings => true
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'SwiftDate'
pod 'TRVideoView'
pod 'TwicketSegmentedControl'

target 'AppName' do
end
```

`pod install`:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking 3.2.1 (was 3.1.0)
Installing Alamofire 4.8.2 (was 4.6.0)
Installing BRYXBanner 0.8.4 (was 0.8.0)
Installing Crashlytics 3.13.1 (was 3.9.3)
Using DZNEmptyDataSet (1.8.1)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit 5.0.2 (was 4.29.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit 5.0.2 (was 4.29.0)
Installing FBSDKShareKit 5.0.2 (was 4.29.0)
Installing Fabric 1.10.1 (was 1.7.2)
Installing FacebookCore 0.7.0 (was 0.3.0)
Installing Firebase 5.20.2 (was 4.7.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 5.8.1 (was 4.0.5)
Installing FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.2.0)
Installing FirebaseAuth 5.4.2 (was 4.4.0)
Installing FirebaseAuthInterop (1.0.0)
Installing FirebaseCore 5.4.1 (was 4.0.12)
Installing FirebaseCrash 3.1.1 (was 2.0.2)
Installing FirebaseDatabase 5.1.1 (was 4.1.2)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID 3.8.1 (was 2.0.7)
Installing FirebaseMessaging 3.5.0 (was 2.0.7)
Installing FirebaseStorage 3.1.1 (was 2.1.0)
Installing GTMSessionFetcher 1.2.2 (was 1.1.12)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (5.8.1)
Installing GoogleSignIn 4.4.0 (was 4.1.1)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac 2.2.1 (was 2.1.3)
Installing GoogleUtilities (5.8.0)
Installing Instabug 8.4.1 (was 7.3.14)
Using MBProgressHUD (1.1.0)
Installing PromiseKit 6.8.5 (was 4.5.0)
Installing Protobuf 3.8.0 (was 3.5.0)
Installing SDWebImage 5.0.6 (was 4.2.2)
Installing SKPhotoBrowser 6.1.0 (was 4.1.0) <- explicit problem here
Installing SVProgressHUD 2.2.5 (was 2.2.2)
Installing SkyFloatingLabelTextField 3.7.0 (was 3.4.0)
Installing Stripe 15.0.1 (was 11.5.0)
Installing SwiftDate 6.0.3 (was 4.3.0) <- and here
Using TRVideoView (0.1.4)
Installing TwicketSegmentedControl 0.1.2
Using leveldb-library (1.20)
Installing lottie-ios 3.1.0 (was 2.1.5)
Installing nanopb 0.3.901 (was 0.3.8)
Removing Bolts
Removing GTMOAuth2
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 28 dependencies from the Podfile and 41 total pods installed.
```

Steps taken:

- all Xcode cleans - cmd + shift + k, cmd + shift + alt + k, erased Derrived Data
- `pod deintegrate && pod clean` and `pod install`
- closed Xcode
- rebooted mac

The interesting thing is that it seems like nothing affects Xcode state - neither pod updates, nor pod disintegration, they are always there with old versions.

How can I successfully make Xcode see new versions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to explicit state the version on the podfile?
something like:

```
pod 'SKPhotoBrowser', '~> 6.1.0'
pod 'SwiftDate', '~> 6.0.3'
```

and if the problem is solved then you can remove the explicit version.

Comment: It still does not resolve the issue. In the nutshell, it looks like Xcode and the project folder get detached at some point. Sometimes, when I do `pod deintegrate`, everything connected to pods disappears in the Xcode, but usually, it is not. At some point, I updated the pods to the needed version but then started over because of some issues (I need to upgrade the actual project code too). So now, I'm back to square on